# jQuery .ajax request doesn't have any effect

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to make a jquery login system, but when I submit the form, the animated gif appears but nothing else.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
    // Quand le formulaire est envoyé
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        // Fade out
        var html = '<div id="head">Connexion en cours...</div>'+
            '<div style="width:100%; text-align: center; margin-top:80px;"><span id="status">Prise de contact avec le serveur</span><span id="img"><br><img src="../img/loaders/bar_blue.gif"></span></div>';
        replaceandfade('#center',html, 10);
                $('#user').attr("disabled", true); 
                $('#pswd').attr("disabled", true); 
                var user = $('#user').val();
                var pswd = $('#pswd').val();
                // On envoie les infos de connexion
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_login.php",
                    data: "user=bob&pswd=bob",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#status").html("En attente de la réponse");
                        alert(data);
                        if(data.login == "failed"){
                            $("#img").html('');
                            $("#status").html("Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe saisie est invalide");
                        } else if(data.login == "success"){
                            $("#status").html("Connexion aprouvé, un instant...");
                        } else {
                            $("#status").html("Une erreur est survenu.");
                        };
                    }
                });
    });// END OF #submit.click
}) // END OF onload
```

The ajax_login.php page returns: `{"login":"failed"}`

But for now it doesn't do anything.

`replaceandfade` function

```
function replaceandfade(div, content, sec) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(div).fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(div).html(content);
            $(div).fadeIn("fast", function() {});
        });
    }, sec)
}
```

Comment: is the alert being called?  What is the reply from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request doesn't handle the error outcome, and so if the request fails (for example the server could not be found, or more likely the response is a 500 server error), then nothing will happen.

You can add a error handler using the `error` function, for example:

```
$.ajax({
    // Other parameters
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Request failed");
    }
});
```

Alternatively (or additionally) you can use the `complete` function to specify actions that should happen when the request ends, be it with a success or fail outcome.

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information.

Comment: Ouch! I thought that `data: "user=bob&pswd=bob"` was sending out values to the URL, i fixed the problem with `url: "ajax_login.php?user="+user+"&pswd="+pswd` in the .ajax request. Thank you for the error handler :)